# SQL Query to select Between two days of the month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to have a SQL Query that selects between two dates of months.

Lets say between the 15th and the 15th of the next month.

This is for accounting purposes

I know with each month having different days adding 30 days or 31 days to the start date will not work especially in Feb. My accounting run is from the 15th of the month to the 15th of the next month.

My current query for selected dates are as follows

```
SELECT * FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE lbs_date  >=  '" . $dates . "' 
AND lbs_date  <= '" . $datee . "' AND lbs_client='$slcustom1' ORDER BY lbs_date DESC, lbs_time DESC
```

lbs_date start should be the 15th of each month and lbs_date end should be the 15th of the next month

By defining the dates as follow works but it is giving me from the November date to now and I want it from the 15th of this month seeing we have past the 15th of the current month already

```
$first = date('Y-m-15', strtotime("$last -1 month"));
$last = date('Y-m-t');
```

and the query

```
SELECT * FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE lbs_date  >=  '" .    
$first . "' 
AND lbs_date  <= '" . $last . "' ORDER BY lbs_date DESC
```

Basically as we pass the current month 15th I need it to show me the current usage from the current 15th not the previous month 15th to now

Comment: What is the problem with current query?

Comment: Current query uses predefined dates from a form, I want to use static dates so I do not have to use predefined variables

Comment: It's not really clear. If you want to select the date dynamically you can write it as SELECT DATE_FORMAT((NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-15');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want what I understand you want,

```
   SELECT l.* 
     FROM lbs_trace_etrack l
     JOIN (SELECT s.cd, CASE 
             WHEN s.cd >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT(s.cd,'%Y-%m-15')) 
             THEN DATE(DATE_FORMAT(s.cd,'%Y-%m-15'))
             ELSE DATE_SUB(DATE(DATE_FORMAT(s.cd,'%Y-%m-15')), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
               AS start_date
             FROM (SELECT CURDATE() cd) s) d
       ON (TRUE)
    WHERE l.lbs_date  >= d.start_date
      AND l.lbs_date  < d.cd  
      AND l.lbs_client = '$slcustom1' 
 ORDER BY l.lbs_date DESC, l.lbs_time DESC;
```

Please note that you still have the PHP variable `$slcustom1` there.
The JOIN with subselect is motivated by the need to call `CURDATE()` only once, to avoid the rare occasion in which the date might change between two subsequent invocations.
Please check if comparisons `<`, `>=` etc. are what you want.

**Edit:**
I’ve moved the computation of `start_date` to the joined table. Even if in this way I have to call `DATE(DATE_FORMAT())` three times, it is better than to compute `DATE_SUB` for every row, in the case we are in the first half of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Could you able to use mysql day() function for your requirement.

Ex:

```
SELECT day("2016.12.15");
       result:
       15
```

Like wise you can use this function to check whether its "15"

> select day(currentDate())

Comment: is this only solution for his problem?

Answer (score 0):

use `DAY()` function to get specific date

```
select * from My_Table where  day(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d-%m-%Y'))  = 1 or day(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d-%m-%Y'))  = 15;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select group_concat(year(now()),"-",month(now()),"-",15)
```